# Apache Storm : Metrics log file is empty

Tags: logging, apache-storm, log4j2, metrics

I am trying to follow the example here

https://www.endgame.com/blog/storm-metrics-how

here is my storm.yaml

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
- localhost


supervisor.slots.ports:
- 6700
- 6701
- 6702
- 6703
- 6704


nimbus.host: localhost

ui.port: 8080
ui.host: localhost

storm.log.dir: /path/to/storm/logdir

topology.max.spout.pending: 5000
```

I tried running the topology in local and cluster mode. the metrics.log file is created at the location `/path/to/storm/logdir` but the file is empty! am i missing some configuration?

Comment: what version of Storm are you using?

Comment: i am using storm version 1.0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the current **log4j2** setup of **Metrics in Storm** and the fix is a little involved.

### Issues

Firstly let me list some bugs from Storm's Jira. Reading the issues and fixes sheds a good amount of light onto the issue at hand with metrics logging:

- [`STORM-584` whole cluster is sharing the metrics log](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-584)
- [`STORM-1673` package rename of `LoggingMetricsConsumer`missed metrics logger setup](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1673)
- [`STORM-1767` naming logger using fully qualified class name creates problems](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1767)

To summarise the situation above:

- Defining **metrics** logger in `cluster.xml` is not right as worker loggers (where metrics are being logged from) are defined using `worker.xml`. So it's possible that a worker will not have access to the metrics logger definition. It also creates problems of file ownership - the first worker to log metrics would own the log file preventing other loggers in other workers from appending to metrics log file.
- After the rename of the package from `backtype.storm.metric` to `org.apache.storm.metric` the package rename missed `worker.xml` file.
- Finally the metrics logger is named `org.apache.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer` which means that when trying to create it using `LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingMetricsConsumer.class)` inside the `LoggingMetricsConsumer` class, the logger that is actually created is a logger attached to **ROOT** logger and using `A1` appender instead of `METRICS` appender.

### The fix

The actual fix for me involved 2 things (please note that first step is optional)

1. Optionally sorting out **log4j2** setup in `worker.xml` and `cluster.xml` files.
   Simply make sure your logging setup has the metrics logger defined in `worker.xml` like it is in this [github commit for Storm project fixing the `STORM-1673` issue (which has made it to `1.0.0` and `2.0.0`)](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/175beec7e5b787f51fe4bc772c48bdb4ec41fc20/log4j2). Conversely please also make sure that the metrics logger is no longer defined in the `cluster.xml` file anymore.
2. Renaming the metrics logger and forking `LoggingMetricsConsumer` class to point it at a newly renamed logger (unatached to **root** logger):
   **Firstly** make sure your metrics logger in `worker.xml` file is no longer named `org.apache.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer` but say `METRICS_LOGGER` as per this snippet:

   ```
   <Logger name="METRICS_LOGGER" level="info" additivity="false">
       <appender-ref ref="METRICS"/>
   </Logger>
   ```

   **Secondly** "fork" `LoggingMetricsConsumer` class from the same [github commit as above](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/175beec7e5b787f51fe4bc772c48bdb4ec41fc20/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/metric/LoggingMetricsConsumer.java).
   Please also note that by *fork* I mean whatever it takes to bring its source code into your project in order to modify it. You can also define your own class implementing `IMetricsConsumer` as long as you then attach it to your topology. Once you have your own `LoggingMetricsConsumer` class you have to modify the way it creates its metrics logger to:

   `public static final Logger METRICS_LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("METRICS_LOGGER");`

### Last note if you are using version of Storm different than 1.0.0 or 2.0.0

Just make sure you look at the `LoggingMetricsConsumer` source code and the versions of `worker.xml` and `cluster.xml` from the git branch your version has been cut from. This area has changed a lot and each change is not backwards compatible (package rename, logger move).