# apache storm 1.0.2 logging: logs are empty

Tags: logging, apache-storm

I'm debugging a storm topology (1.0.2) but directories for logs are filled with empty files. I tried to switch on logging by:

- switching different kinds of logging level for ROOT (debug, info, etc) in the storm UI for a topology
- explicitly specifying TOPOLOGY_LOGGING_SENSITIVITY (to the lowest S0 level) in the storm Config
- explicitly allowing users and groups (LOGS_USERS/LOGS_GROUPS) in the storm Config.

I found the question on the similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842327/apache-storm-metrics-log-file-is-empty), concerning metrics logs, but, as I understood it, the problem is in the class paths for the particular logging classes. That's strange, if such problem stays for the *all* loggers in storm.

Comment: If I did not know a thing about Java, I would make sure that the logfiles are kept open by the correct process (using `lsof`) and that disabling selinux does not magically fix the issue. Then I would ask a Java or Storm expert.

Comment: I would check permissions first.